# Parent child prop types, why is typescript not giving me a warning here?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im just starting out with typescript and this example might be a bit convoluted but I'm trying to understand why typescript isnt giving me a warning in this scenario

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xu7bva?file=Parent.tsx,Child.tsx,App.tsx,package.json

In Parent.tsx , recordDetail is of type `IRecordDetail` when passing to Child on line 30

`<Child recordDetail={recordDetail} />`

but the prop interface specified on Child is of type `IRecordItemDetail`

```
interface IRecordItemDetail {
  name: string;
  itemNumber: string;
}

type ChildProps = {
  recordDetail: IRecordItemDetail;
};
```

although there is an overlap of fields i would expect a warning that im trying to assign one interface type to a different one. Are my expectations any way correct?

How would i enforce the extra props not to be passed to the Child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a [structural typing system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), not a nominal typing system. A `IRecordDetail` IS an `IRecordItemDetail` since it has both `name` and `itemNumber`...

```js
interface IRecordItemDetail {
  name: string;
  itemNumber: string;
}

interface IRecordDetail {
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  name: string;
  itemNumber: string;
}
```

This differs from a nominal typing system such as Java or C# in which each value is labelled with a unique symbol, and the runtime enforces that the value has that symbol before you can use it as a given type.

In a nominal typing system you couldn't substitute values just because they happen to have the same structure, because the symbols wouldn't match (unless they had an inheritance relationship). However in Typescript you can (and it's part of the philosophy really).

Comment: By the way, as a non C# reader, prefixing every interface with `I` seems an unfortunate convention (like calling a variable `countNumber` because it's a number - redundant in a typed system). When your type system demands that IRecordItemDetail is not an interface but is a type instead, will you rename it? Violates SOLID.

Comment: thanks for the link... how would i go about enforcing that the start and end dates arent passed? Probably should have asked this in the question, will update

Comment: Enforcing the runtime values is a matter of logic in Javascript as the type system has a very slim capability to reason about actual values.